# Dual boot Windows 10 fail to start: "Recovery your PC needs to be repaired"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 along with my Windows 10 installation. I first changed the boot order on my BIOS as follow:

1. CDrom
2. Windows Boot manager

Then, I chose to install Ubuntu in a "Dual Boot" configuration. Everything went fine and at the reboot grub was there. If I choose Ubuntu, I boot to Ubuntu. If I choose Windows 10 I get a blue screen:

```
Recovery
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed

0xC000000E

Enter to continue
F8 for startup settings
```

None of the two options works (I stick to this screen).

Now, If I go back to my BIOS settings and place `Windows boot manager` on the first position, Windows boot, but grub does not show.

It seems that Windows absolutely want its `Windows boot manager` to be first.

I don't have any `Secure Boot` option available anywhere.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Refer to your system user manual..secure boot needs to be disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Grub only can boot Working Windows, or one that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk (always after a resize). And Windows 10 fast start up is always on hibernation. http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation